# filesink not working for a small program from inside an application

Tags: c, h.264, gstreamer, glib

The following `gst-launch` line works

```
gst-launch-0.10    filesrc location=ElementaryStream.h264  ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! filesink location=filetest821
```

This results in a dump of a decoded elementary stream, that is expected!

While ...

when the same sample gstreamer code is run from inside an application a C++ ( yes C++ program), test file is of **zero** bytes.

Have checked the following possible -
- permissions at the location
- all the elements creation
- check/ give full path

Also have to check the following, your suggestions ?

- a glib main loop is running from this sample gstreamer code, the C++ application uses many threads. Could this be an issue ?

P.S. Data comes fine after source (dumped using a filesink), and also after parser( dumped using a filesink)

Comment: Couple suggestions which could help with debugging this, 1. Have you tried giving the filesink a full path? Eg. location=/tmp/filetest821 2. If that doesn't work, could you please run $ strace your_cpp_application | tee -a ~/strace.your_cpp_application.log 2>&1 and post the results? That will trace your entire application as it runs and print out how it allocates memory/writes to disk etc with all the system calls that linux is using in the background. If you paste that in a pastebin I think I could help you identify the issue.